# How to use deep relative trust to measure the distance between two RNNs, and between two transformers?

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks, transformer

I want to measure how different two networks, i.e., between two RNNs and between
two transformers. I read that [Deep relative trust](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2020/file/f4b31bee138ff5f7b84ce1575a738f95-Paper.pdf) can be used to measure the distance between two NNs. Can it be used on RNNs and Transformers?

Because in the paper, as far as I understand, it is only applied to MLPs?
Can I simply loop for each layer and compute the deep relative trust?

I want to plot the difference (distance) between two neural nets (as the x axis) vs the differece between the two nets' generated solution (as the y axis)?

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to do this? One could define a lot of similarity measures (e.g. number of parameters, number of layers of the same type, etc), but each may be useful in one case but not another. So, maybe you could explain why you want to do this.

Comment: I have added the intended usage. I'm still wondering though if it is logical/rational for that use..